# Sample Program UIMA CFE(Cofigurable Feature Extractor)

Tags: uima

I'm working under *UIMA* and i need to know the *CFE* in *UIMA*. i gone through Apache documentation *CFE* User Guide but i unable to get clarity regarding *CFE* in *UIMA*. I need to get more clarification on *CFE UIMA*. any one please help to explain the concept of *CFE* with sample coding.

Thanks in Advance.